# Where can I find "C/C++ Users Journal" code archive?

Tags: c++, archive, journal

The articles can be found from Dr. Dobb's web site, but I can't find the links to the source code anywhere. I'm looking at this article in particular (http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184403758). Googling around seems to suggest that the source code used to be at http://www.cuj.com/code/archive.htm or ftp.cuj.com/pub/ but neither of those sites are alive anymore. I have also tried webArchive but they don't have it.

Anyone knows any mirror or back up sites that contain those code files?

Comment: Better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com.  This isn't a programming question.

Comment: It is about code so makes sense here

Comment: @John Dibling:  It's a perfectly objective question, not about programmers per se, and therefore doesn't belong on programmers.se.

Comment: FYI, I've just found a modified version of the ScopeGuard classes mentioned in the article from here: http://www.zete.org/people/jlehrer/scopeguard.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DDJ and CUJ source code are archived here:
http://www.drdobbs.com/sourcecode/index.jhtml

Answer (score 5):

The Dr. Dobbs archive is available on DVD.  See https://store.ddj.com/product/13/Dr.-Dobb%27s-Developer-Library-DVD-Release-6.

Comment: Can't find using this link anymore. Anyone know where to get it from?

Comment: You can access most of the Dr. Dobbs archives at http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/dr-dobbs-archive/240169474.  I tried searching for the article number.  Is this the article you are looking for: "Generic: Change the Way You Write Exception-Safe Code — Forever
By Andrei Alexandrescu and Petru Marginean, December 01, 2000"?